# What is the difference of "can" and "may" in this case?

Tags: word-meaning

https://careers.jobscore.com/jobs2/bustle?sid=68 -> This is a media website and I occasionally opened its jobs page. I noticed that some of the jobs are with "can work remotely" while one is "may work remotely":

```
EDITORIAL (BUSTLE)

Books Feature Writers (can work remotely)   New York, NY
Entertainment Writers (may work remotely)   New York, NY
Fashion/Beauty Writers (can work remotely)  New York, NY
Freelance Writers/Reporters (can work remotely) New York, NY
Lifestyle News Writers (can work remotely)  New York, NY
```

And there is another job:

```
News Writer (can be remote) New York, NY
```

Does `can be remote` 100% equals to `can work remotely`?

What is the difference of `can` and `may` here?

Hopefully to get some detailed information on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Generally: "Can" = I will and am ready to work remotely. "Will" = I can and will work remotely *if needed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ads you are asking about, the intent of using **can** and **may** look to be the same. Keep in mind, **different people** have written these adverts, so their **individual usages** may vary.

Keep in the back of your mind:

> **Can work remotely** = ability, **to be able** to work remotely
>   **May** = permission, **to be allowed** to work remotely
>
> Usually, one needs to be granted permission **before** one's able to perform.

A finer point of difference between the two phrasings might be:

> **can work remotely** means that the person does not have to show up in an office setting. Since the employer is already making the offer to **work remotely**, one can assume the applicant has been **granted permission**
>
> **may work remotely** means the employer is **giving permission to work remotely**, however this may be dependent on the applicant's skill level.

> **can be remote 100** is equivalent to **working remotely**

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case the job advertisers are not being careful with their English usage, which is reasonable in such a small piece of text, and "may" and "can" are being used the same way.  Also "remote" and "remotely" are 100% equal in this context (thought I feel that remotely is better English).

Answer (score 1):

The words appear to mean the same thing here.

When I was in school my teachers made a big deal that "can" refers to ability and "may" refers to permission. So for example if you said, "You may stand up now", you mean that you are giving the person permission to stand up. But, "You can stand up now" is recognizing that the person is capable of standing (perhaps he has overcome a physical problem). But in common use, "can" is used for both ability and permission. If you say, "Can I drive your car?", you are almost certainly asking the other person to loan it to you, not asking if he knows whether you are capable.

"Remote" is an adjective. "Remotely" is an adverb. So a person can be remote, or you can work remotely. You can't "work remote" or "be remotely". In context I'd think the two phrases mean the same thing. Perhaps it's worth noting that, in general, if you say a person "is remote", you mean that he is not interacting with other people, that is, that he is distracted or aloof. Like, "Since his divorce, Bob has become very remote", meaning, he doesn't talk to anybody. But it's very unlikely that a want ad would say that it's okay if you're aloof.